# How do edit/pose/object positions relate to another?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, pose-mode, object-mode

This is confusing me a lot. One object can have different positions in Edit, Object and Pose mode. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> resets the object's position to what? The object's origin? Then how come sometimes the result of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> differs between the different modes?

Then there's Rest position and Pose position, adding more confusion.

Comment: Are you talking about an armature? In Object mode, Alt R, Alt S and Alt G will act like for any object, it will reset the rotation, scale and location. In Pose mode it will bring back the bones to their rest pose, i.e. the location, rotation and scale that you set in Edit mode. In Edit mode, these shortcuts are useless (Alt R seems to do something, not sure what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Object Mode**, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> resets any object to the *world origin*.

In **Pose Mode**, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> brings a bone back to its *rest pose*.

When you move an object with a bone in *Pose Mode*, the object's mesh in *Edit Mode* remains at the point it was last moved/rotated in *Object Mode*.

And *Pose Position* is just the pose position in *Pose Mode*.